# (Soft Question) Why do textbook authors pretend that their advanced math texts have no prerequisites and are completely accessible?

Tags: soft-question

Number Theory by George E. Andrews, which is apparently accessible to liberal arts majors, contains this beautiful equation:

$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(b+a)(b+aq)...(b+aq^{n-1})z^n}{(1-q)(1-q^2)...(1-q^n)}}=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1+azq^n}{1-bzq^n}}$$

while Analytic Number Theory by Apostol, which is apparently accessible to "sophisticated high school students," contains the following

$$\sum_{p\le x\text{, }p \equiv h (\text{mod k})}{\frac{\text{log }p}{p}}=\frac{1}{\phi(k)}\text{log }x+\frac{1}{\phi(k)}\sum^{\phi(k)}_{r=2}{\bar{\chi}_r(h)\sum^{ }_{p \le x}{\frac{\chi_r(p) \text{log } p}{p}}}+O(1)$$

Both books are fairly old. Have our standards for education changed? Are the authors crazy? Any thoughts would be appreciated :)

Comment: there are very crazy books that contain the adjective “introductory” or “introduction to___” in the title. I’ve learnt to ignore that particular word.

Comment: Same remark with the word “clearly” in any math book :) Sometimes it’s actually clear, sometimes it’s not (and sometimes, it may seem clear initially but then you think about it and it’s actually not).

Comment: 1. These descriptions seem to be given by the authors themselves, and therefore should be taken with a grain of salt (or ignored). 2. The context of the quote from Apostol's book clarifies that "high school students" is mostly referring to course prerequisites, i.e. don't need to know calculus; if you understand chapters 1 to n, then in principle you are equipped to understand chapter n+1. This says nothing about the mathematical maturity needed to parse/understand the book though, which I guess is why he adds "sophisticated."

Comment: Who is making these claims for the books? (I was reading Apostol in high school, but I was far from a usual case, because I also took a functional analysis class in high school.) in any event, attacking claims about books without giving us the source of the claims seems not useful.

Comment: Also, the prerequisites of books doesn't mean that, by the time you reach these results, the readers' sophistication will still be elementary. If you start any math book on page $200,$ you are likely to be mystified. The whole point of most math books is to take you from the simple to the more complex.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews For the Andrews book, the quote is from the [publisher's description of the book](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486682528.html). For the Apostol book, the quote is from the [preface by the author](https://imgur.com/a/xvOxoGB).

Comment: *"Have our standards for education changed?"* I think so, but your question is very badly posed. To add to the previous comments, with which I fully agree: it's entirely different to have an exercise that asks to prove these formulas from scratch without help, and to have a long, guided problem to get to them. For instance in high school a teacher once gave me a problem that led to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Each step was rather straightforward. You can't judge the difficulty of a book by a random formula taken from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course a literal answer to the question is impossible -- one would have to at least be able to interview all of the authors and get a range of answers.  So I'll try to say what I suspect the most significant answers are, in most cases.

1. Textbook authors grew up in a different context than most other people.

An important different context is the time when they grew up.  In the 1960s and before, college students were much more uniform in their educational background.  If you went to college it was extremely likely that you already had been through a relatively elite high school or secondary school education.  As education became accessible to lower classes, the student body became much more diverse in many good ways.  But it did mean that background assumptions that the professor could make about the students, no longer held.

Anyway, long story short: When a textbook author thinks of a student, very often they have a specific idea of "a student who is now like I was when I took this class" and that assumption is often very wrong.

2. Math uniquely suffers from the fact that when you understand a mathematical topic, you struggle to imagine not understanding it.

I can't prove this is true, but from personal experience I just know that things which I struggled to understand when I took classes, now appear so transparent that I literally have to make an effort to be sympathetic when young students don't understand it.  I like to believe that I am generous and patient -- but when a student fails to understand basic theorems about cyclic groups immediately, I just instinctively think "How can you not understand?" And then I remember that I had the same confusions at one time, and professors looked at me undoubtedly thinking "How can you not understand?"  So I try to hide my reactions, but they are just involuntary reactions.

Anyway, the point is: it is very easy to be a little less introspective, and think that anyone should understand all this stuff immediately and with not much explanation.

3. Advertising your book as not needing prerequisites might get you more sales.

Mercenary, but a little bit true.  The more you can convince a publisher that every person on the planet should buy your book, the better.